# Using Process.extract in fuzzywuzzy and the all max similar choices for given query and choices

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, python-requests

```
query = ('Hello','bye' , 'yellow')
choices= ('Hello','can', 'sweet' , 'lye' , 'fellow' , 'Hello')
```

Now I want to use fuzzywuzzy process. Extract() to get the best choice with maximum similarity ratio for all of my queries. And if there are two choices with the same maximum ratio, I want both of them.

My expected output is-- (list for similarity ratio for all my query elements)

```
('Hello', 100), ('Hello', 100)]
('lye' , 80)
('fellow' , 80 )
```

Comment: Strings similarity is a large domain. 1. can we say anagrams are 100% match 2. Like `bye` and `lye` - can we expect both of same size?, then we can do charecter to charecter comparision. 3. Why are `bye` and `lye` are 80% match, should be 66% match right? 4. What is your goal? Can you inlucde some more content for readers please

Comment: ('lye' , 80) and ('fellow' , 80 ) were just as examples of output that only one match of bye and yellow from the query was available from choices. what i want is best choices for all the query elements and if there are two best choices available like the hello element i want both in that case if there are two choices with max ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/

An example from above link page.

```
>>> choices = ["Atlanta Falcons", "New York Jets", "New York Giants", "Dallas Cowboys"]
>>> process.extract("new york jets", choices, limit=2)
    [('New York Jets', 100), ('New York Giants', 78)]
>>> process.extractOne("cowboys", choices)
    ("Dallas Cowboys", 90)
```